# Delete a line from the following table

Tags: tikz-pgf

With the following codes, I get

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{arrow style/.style = {blue,->,> = latex',
shorten > = 6pt,
shorten < = 6pt}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=5]{$x$ /1, $f(x)$ /1.5, $g(x)$ /2}{$0$ ,$1$ , $+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{d,-,z,+,}
\tkzTabVar%
{ D+/ / $0$ ,%
-/ -2/ ,+/ $+\infty$ / }%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

> I want to delete the first line of the above table. i.e., I want to get

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{arrow style/.style = {blue,->,> = latex',
shorten > = 6pt,
shorten < = 6pt}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=5]{$x$ /1, $g(x)$ /1}
                    {$0$ ,$1$ , $+\infty$}%
\tkzTabVar%
{ D+/ / $0$ ,%
-/ -2/ ,+/ $+\infty$ / }%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```